# Filebeat registry data.json is empty

Tags: logstash, filebeat, elk

I am trying to setup **filebeat**, but it **not harvesting logs** at all from the given log file path.

After lot of research, I came to know that **data.json in registry folder is empty** which is why filebeat is unable to read logs from log file.

Can someone please suggest how to fix this?

**Note** :- there is no error in filebeat logs saying permission denied to write into data.json

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/mahesh/Documents/refactor/nomi/unity/media/*.log

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

Comment: Can you add your .conf file of your pipeline

Comment: @RanikaNisal its working now, just had to add few more parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also meet the trouble as you mentioned above, but i don't know reason. I'm using filebeat 7.8.0. my config is the following:

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      templates:
        - condition:
            contains:
              docker.container.image: log:latest
          config:
            - type: log
              paths:
                - /var/lib/docker/containers/${data.docker.container.id}/*-json.log

output.elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["http://es01:9200"]

setup.template.name: "filebeat-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template.pattern: "filebeat-*"
setup.ilm.enabled: false
```